# Python/Pandas - Generate All Possible Combinations of a Parsed Categorical (Binary) Variable

Tags: python, pandas, math, combinations

I have a dataset that roughly takes on this simplified form:

```
id       Fan    Pos
10001   32.83   A/B
10005   71.60   A/B
10010   24.23   E/F
10011   48.81   G/H
```

I need to 'unpack' the Pos variable and generate n different versions of the dataset with all possible combinations of the parsed Pos variable. The end result needs to be a Pandas df something like this:

```
Set   id    Fan    Pos
1   10001   32.83   A
1   10005   71.60   A
1   10010   24.23   E
1   10011   48.81   G
2   10001   32.83   A
2   10005   71.60   A
2   10010   24.23   E
2   10011   48.81   H
.   .          .    .
.   .          .    .
.   .          .    .
16  10001   32.83   B
16  10005   71.60   B
16  10010   24.23   F
16  10011   48.81   H
```

In this case, there are 2^4 = 16 unique combinations of the Pos variable across the 4 rows (see below). Notice that each Set above is 1 of the 16 combinations listed below in terms of the Pos variable.

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B
A   A   A   A   B   B   B   B   A   A   A   A   B   B   B   B
E   E   F   F   E   E   F   F   E   E   F   F   E   E   F   F
G   H   G   H   G   H   G   H   G   H   G   H   G   H   G   H
```

The thing is that this process will be recurring and the number of rows will change, which of course means the number of combos will change (2^nrows = ? for the future).

My first idea is to hard code a series of loops to do this, but since the number of rows will change in the future, the number of loops would have to be dynamically link to the number of rows.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

combs = df.apply(lambda x: [(x.name, c) for c in x['Pos'].split('/')], axis=1)

df_out = pd.Series(product(*combs)).explode().to_frame().reset_index()
df_out.index, df_out[0] = df_out[0].str[0], df_out[0].str[1]

df_out = pd.merge(df, df_out, left_index=True, right_index=True).sort_values(by=['index', 0])

df_out = df_out.rename(columns={'index': 'Set', 0: 'Pos'})
df_out['Set'] += 1
print(df_out[['Set', 'id', 'Fan', 'Pos']])
```

Prints:

```
   Set     id    Fan  Pos Pos
0    1  10001  32.83  A/B   A
1    1  10005  71.60  A/B   A
2    1  10010  24.23  E/F   E
3    1  10011  48.81  G/H   G
0    2  10001  32.83  A/B   A
1    2  10005  71.60  A/B   A
2    2  10010  24.23  E/F   E
3    2  10011  48.81  G/H   G
0    3  10001  32.83  A/B   A
1    3  10005  71.60  A/B   A

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
from itertools import product

d = df['Pos'].str.split('/', expand=True).T

pd.concat([df[['id', 'Fan']].assign(Pos=x)
          for x in product(*[d[col] for col in d.columns])])
```

Output:

```
       id    Fan Pos
0   10001  32.83   A
1   10005  71.60   A
2   10010  24.23   E
3   10011  48.81   G
0   10001  32.83   A
..    ...    ...  ..
3   10011  48.81   G
0   10001  32.83   B
1   10005  71.60   B
2   10010  24.23   F
3   10011  48.81   H

[64 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This looks spot on for the situation I described. I am running tests right now. Unfortunately, I downplayed the size of the actual problem: The example I gave here was 2^4 = 16 combinations. In actuality, I have something more like 2^50 ~ 1.125 quadrillion. As I am sure you can imagine, I am having RAM issues. Do you have any idea the max number of combinations the itertools product function can handle (or is the bottleneck mostly the RAM of the computer)?

Comment: @Dan: It is expected that you will run into memory issues with so many combinations. I would advise you to avoid creating a dataframe with all possible rows. Instead, you should do the calculations you need row by row, but without creating a dataframe. If you have a computer with several cores, it will help to parallelize the computations (for instance, you might use `dask`).